# (flutter) Some UIs of my app displays differently when running on my mac m1, compared to the same source code running on different PCs

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Recently I downloaded the flutter SDK, cloned the project repo from Github, and tried to ran the app. But some widgets are missing or displayed incorrectly, compared to the one built and ran on my co-worker's PC. Cannot post the code here since this is a project of my company. But here are some photos:

For example, here is the one on my mac:

[Here is the one on my mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktqDT.png)

[Here is the one on her PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j9aX.png)

Note that this happens when running on both android emulators and ios simulators.

Here is my flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.16.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9e1c857886 (3 days ago) • 2023-11-30 11:51:18 -0600
Engine • revision cf7a9d0800
Tools • Dart 3.2.2 • DevTools 2.28.3
```

Here is her flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.13.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ead455963c (9 weeks ago) • 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
Engine • revision a794cf2681
Tools • Dart 3.1.2 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

I've tried to downgrade the flutter SDK to the same version as my coworker but the problem could not be solved. The only way to fix this problem is to make changes to the code, but I really want to know the root cause of the problem since I'm new to flutter.

Is it because we're using different flutter SDK and dependencies versions or is there something missing on my mac?

Comment: Can you tell at least what widget that appears different?

Answer (score 0):

its just because there is some Different widget for ios and android which look different . that's because ios uses cupertino but android use material style .
try to find equivalent widgets base on the platform you are trying to use .
you can detect which platform your app is running on with

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Android-specific code
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS-specific code
}
```

then use it to show different widgets base on that .